# I need to add the items from list A to list B, only when the item already exists in list B

Tags: python-3.x

I need to add all the items in list A in to list B, if and only if the items already exist in list B, even if there are multiple items that are same in list A. How can I do this? Right now, it stops after the first of the same words. Say for example, List A is [the, a, sure, book, is, the, best], and list B is [the, rock], I need to add the two "the"s in list A to list B, to make a total of three "the"s in list B

It's for a beginner's class in python. I've tried different formats of the for loop, but it doesn't seem to work. There is a for loop before this, that creates the list B, I think it maybe because of the back to back for loops.

```
for word in list_a:
    if word[0].isupper() == True:
        list_b.append(word)

list_b = [word.lower() for word in list_b]

for word in list_a:
    if word in list_b:
        list_b.append(word)

list_b = [word.capitalize() for word in list_b]
```

The second for loop is the one giving me trouble. I have pasted the larger code which I am trying to work with. So my main objective is to first separate the words that are capitalized in list A in to list B.

Then lowercase list B, so I can find the same words in list A that are not capitalized, and then add those to list B as well. Then capitalize all of list B again to print the count.

I know that there is an easier way to do this, where I can just make the original string lowercase and then work from there. However, in this case I need to keep track of the words that were originally capitalized, because when I print the words with their total counts, the words that were originally capitalized, need to print in their capitalized form rather than the lowercase form.

Therefore, the expected outcome I am looking for is list B as [the, rock, the, the].

Comment: So what is the original `list_a` and `list_b` before you start your first for loop, can you share that instead, and the final output as well

Comment: It's dynamic list, not any particular list. It's sentence input from the user, so it depends on what the user is entering. I am breaking up each sentence into words, and then storing it in list_a, until the user quits. Once all the words are in, the above function kicks in.

So,
list_a only has 'strings' as items.
list_b is empty at the beginning of this function.

Comment: Then please pick an example, work it out by hand, and paste the list_a before and `list_b` after the code is run, which will help us work out what might be going on

Comment: Okay say, the user enters following strings:

"The house of thunder."
"Cat jumped over the moon."
"Python is the best."

Before the function is run.

list_a = [The, house, of, thunder, Cat, jumped, over, the, moon, Python, is, the, best]
list_b = []

After the first For loop

list_a is same, no change
list_b = [The, Cat, Python]

And as you can see then I have the function to lowercase list_b.

In the second For loop, I am trying to identify lowercase words that are also in list_b, so those words can be added as many times as they occur in the lowercase form in list_a.

Comment: With what I currently have, it only adds the first lowercase "the" from list_a to list_b and does not add the ones later in list_a.

Comment: So the expected output will be `['The', 'The', 'The'] right?

Comment: No, expected outcome will be ['The', 'Cat', 'Python', 'The', 'The']

Comment: So words in uppercase in list_a, which were also repeated in lowercase in that list, is your output?

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Comment: Sure, before I come up with a refactored approach, you might want to check the answer already posted, and if any of them work for you, you can accept them

Comment: I added an answer below @JaskaranSinghGhag using the list you shared, I just divided the logic into two steps, please check below and let me know any question s you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ['the', 'a', 'sure', 'book', 'is', 'the', 'best']
b = ['the', 'rock']

b = b + [text for text in a if text in b]
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same issue, where it is only counting the first instance of the same word, and if it repeats again, it just ignores it.

Comment: @JaskaranSinghGhag that's weird. are we using the exact same lists??? there might be a need to process the text like `strip()`

Comment: they're the exact same lists. No changes done to list_a, and only list_b is being changed in the first for loop, and in the one you suggested, but still doesn't work.

Would list_a need to be processed or list_b?

Comment: but the result we're getting is the one you want i.e. `['the', 'rock', 'the', 'the']`?

Comment: No, it was not working before. but when you mentioned you were getting the results I wanted. I tried to see if I had something wrong. There was a line above the For loop, which was interfering, so when I moved it to the bottom, IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_b = list_b + ([x for x in list_a if x in list_b])
```

result:

```
['the', 'rock', 'the', 'the']
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same issue, where it is only counting the first instance of the same word, and if it repeats again, it just ignores it.

Comment: what do you mean exactly , i got the correct result as you mentioned in the answer?